# GAE Datastore Entity relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

To make entity relationship we put a parent `Key` (parent relationship) or put a Key into a `Entity` property (child relationship).

Like this:

```
Key resultingKey = KeyFactory.createKey(parent, kind, key);
Entity userEntity = new Entity(resultingKey); // parent

Entity oldAddress = new Entity(KeyFactory.createKey(e.getKey, "Address", userEntity.getOldAddress.getId()));

userEntity.setProperty("oldAddress", oldAddress.getKey()); // child
```

However the question would be, for a parent Key, does the key should be a product of a Datastore put:

```
Key resultingKey = _ds.put(parentEntity);
```

Or creating a Key with KeyFactory is enough?

Furthermore, does this apply also for child `Key`?

Answer (score 0):

> KeyFactory class enables direct creation of Key objects, both in the
>   root entity group (no parent) and as the child of a given parent.

For More information : [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory)